# Textalignment in a Textbox in VBA - strange behaviour

Tags: vba, textbox, userform, ms-forms

I'm trying to align text in a textbox to the right side. Either through code `TextBox.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight` or setting the property "directly".

Unfortunately, it becomes left-aligned as soon as the text (string) gets too big to be displayed fully in the textbox. Like this example which has all letters from a to z (`abcdefghijklmnropqrstuvwxyz`) and should be right-aligned, but it's not:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to change this behavior / how to force the alignment? Thanks!

Comment: I can't replicate that. More details required I think.

Comment: What if you set the property in the properties window.

Comment: @SJR it's right-aligned as well. I added a screenshot in my question.

Comment: The closest thing I can find that kinda works is to set the `SelStart` property to the length of the textbox's contents, but it gets reset once it loses and regains focus. I am curious as to why you desire this behavior.

Comment: @braX Only the last 4 characters of the string are the once important to me, which are not visible as long it's left-aligned.

Comment: How about leaving the textbox alone and adding an autosized label that just displays the last 4 characters of the textbox?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - yes, that was going to be my next suggestion/question - or at least something similar... why use a textbox if you dont want it to behave like a normal textbox...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon sorry I wasn't specific enough. After I check the last 4 characters, from time to time I need to check the left characters as well. In some cases, I need to select copy the whole value (that's why I'm using the textbox).

Comment: Sounds like you need a wider textbox, is all. Tweaking how MSForms controls behave is the very, very, **very** last thing you should do/attempt.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon In this case, I need the textbox to be a specific (max) size. As a workaround, I made the font smaller, which works in most cases but is far from optimal.

Comment: Seeing your actual form, with some actual input, would help us help you. As it stands, I doubt you'll end up with an answer. The people that commented here are all very knowledgeable answerers... if your question was answerable as-is, it would already be answered. Consider editing to clarify.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon ok, thanks for your help so far. So, as far as I understand this is VBA's regular behavior, right?

Comment: Not just VBA's ....pretty much how textboxes on Windows have been behaving for >30 years. Hence why changing their behavior isn't recommended.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Ok, thanks. Then I'll think I expand on your suggestion and cut the string after x amount of characters so it always fits the box and add an event that shows the whole string once I click inside the box. Is it possible to reopen the question, so I can post my answer as a workaround?

Comment: Just an idea: did you code a `.SelStart = 0` somewhere else, @Albin?

Comment: @T.M. No, I did not. But as far as I understand braX's comment I would have to set `TextBox.SellStart = TextBox.TextLength` in Order for it to work?!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this `TextBox` has the property `Enabled` set to false. You need to turn it on, and then the `TextAlign` property will work as you wish. Also, you can use this function:

```
Public Function SetTextBox(itm1 As MSForms.textbox, ByVal txtAlign1 As MSForms.fmTextAlign)
    Dim notEnabled1 As Boolean
    If Not itm1.Enabled Then itm1.Enabled = True: notEnabled1 = True
    itm1.SetFocus
    itm1.TextAlign = txtAlign1
    itm1.SelStart = Len(itm1.Text)
    If notEnabled1 Then itm1.Enabled = False
End Function
```